# The length of the derivative operator Derivative[1,0] in (c^(1,0))[t,x] is not the same as the number of arguments

Tags: differential-equations

I´m trying to solve these PDE´s but I can´t. Can someone help me please?

`NDSolve[{D[c[t, x], t] == (1/x^2)*D[x^2*D[c[t, x], x], x] +  k*(s[t, x])^(2/3)*(cs - c[t, x]), D[s[t, x], t] == -k*(s[t, x])^(2/3)*(cs - c[t, x]), c[0, x] == 0,  s[0, x] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][c][t, 0] == 0, c[t, 1] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][s][t, 0] == 0, s[t, 1] == (1 - k*cs*t/3)^3}, c, s, {t, 0, 3}, {x, 0, 1}];`

NDSolve::derlen: The length of the derivative operator Derivative[1,0] in (c^(1,0))[t,x] is not the same as the number of arguments.

Comment: Plus you need to put {c,s} in as the dependent variables, you haven't got the list around them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few issues with your attempt.

1. Since you are using `NDSolve`, so you need to specify numerical values for the different parameters involved, i.e., `k` and `cs`.
2. The DE for `s[t,x]` is of the first order, so you cannot take initial/boundary condition on the derivative and you cannot have more than one initial/boundary condition.
3. In first PDE, you have $\frac{1}{x^2}$, which is causing the situation `1/0` when $x=0$, so, I choose the starting value for $x$ to be `10^-4`.

Here is a starting for you,

```
pde1 = D[c[t, x], t] == (1/x^2)*D[x^2*D[c[t, x], x], x] + k*(s[t, x])^(2/3)*(cs - c[t, x]);

pde2 = D[s[t, x], t] == -k*(s[t, x])^(2/3)*(cs - c[t, x]);

cs = 1; k = 1;

sol = NDSolve[{pde1, pde2, c[0, x] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][c][t, 10^-4] == 0, s[0, x] == 1, 
   c[t, 1] == 0}, {c, s}, {t, 0, 3}, {x, 10^-4, 1}];

Plot3D[{c[t, x], s[t, x]} /. sol, {t, 0, 3}, {x, 10^-4, 1}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

As suggested in the comment by @BobHanlon, we can also use `ParametricNDSolve` when we are dealing with parameters in a differential equation.

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{pde1, pde2, c[0, x] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][c][t, 10^-4] == 0, 
s[0, x] == 1, c[t, 1] == 0}, {c, s}, {t, 0, 3}, {x, 10^-4, 1}, {k, cs}];

Plot3D[{c[1, 1][t, x], s[1, 1][t, x]} /. sol, {t, 0, 3}, {x, 10^-4, 1}]
```

Comment: `cs` and `k` can be left as parameters using [`ParametricNDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html)